# Weird behavior of ndarray.tofile

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm switching to Matlab to NumPy/SciPy, and it seems np.fromfile and ndarray.tofile corresopnds to fread and fwrite in Matlab respectively.

Just to test these APIs, I first created a binary file containing five integers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} in binary 'int32' format.

Then, I read this file using np.fromfile.

```
In [365]:

in_file = open('12345.bin', 'rb'); x = np.fromfile(in_file, 'int32'); in_file.close()
```

I checked that it was read successfully as shown below:

```
In [367]:

x

Out[366]:
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Now, I wrote this to as file with a different name. My expectation is this output file should be exactly the same as the original input file, which is '12345.bin'.

```
In [368]:


out_file = open('12345out.bin', 'wb'); x.tofile(out_file, 'int32'); out_file.close()
```

But one surprising thing is the size of '12345out.bin' is 25 bytes, while '12345.bin' is 20 bytes. So something is wrong. I opened '12345out.bin' as follows:

```
In [369]:

in_file = open('12345out.bin', 'rb'); x2 = np.fromfile(in_file, 'int32'); in_file.close()

In [370]:

x2

Out[370]:
array([1953392945, 1764897331,  842232942, 1953392947, 1765028403,
        842232942], dtype=int32)
```

So, from the above result, we see that something is completely wrong. Coud anyone please help me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tofile` doesn't need the type parameter (which is one of the reasons it's not a great tool, because it doesn't preserve type information).  So when you do

```
x.tofile(out_file, 'int32')
```

you're actually saying you want to use the *string* `"int32"` as the *separator* in a text format:

```
>>> x = np.arange(1,6,dtype=np.int32)
>>> x.tofile(open("tmp.dat", "wb"), "int32")
>>> open("tmp.dat","rb").read()
b'1int322int323int324int325'
```

Instead:

```
>>> x = np.arange(1,6,dtype=np.int32)
>>> x.tofile(open("tmp.dat", "wb"))
>>> open("tmp.dat","rb").read()
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00'
>>> np.fromfile("tmp.dat", "int32")
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

(Note that I was too lazy to use a `with` block to open and close files as I should.)